# Почему подключение переферийных устройств к компьютеру реализовано на базе usb, а не на базе витой пары оптоволокна?

Tags: usb, железо, разъёмы

Витая пара в Санкт-Петербурге бывает даже дешевле 20 рублей за метр + наконечники. Шнур USB, по моему скромному мнению, несколько дороже. К примеру, кабель категории 6 имеет более высокую скорость передачи данных по сравнению с usb 3.0 (10 гБит/c по сравненению 5 гБит/c).

**Вопросы:**  Почему витая пара используется только для взаимодействия с сетью? Почему используется usb для мышки клавиатуры и принтера? Если бы мы подключали их по витой паре, они бы работали бы быстрее, ведь для витой пары не нужен усилитель сигнала, в то время как кабеля usb длинее 5 метров без усилителя сигнала не бывает.
Вот только представьте, у вашего компьютера, везде только разъёмы под коннектор RJ-45. В том числе для наушников и микрофона. Полная унификация - полная взаимозаменяемость.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что оборудование с эзернет стоит дороже вреднем на 2-3 тысячи юсбишного - сравните стоимость принтеров. Потому что нужно страивать сетевую карту и контроллер со стеком IP.

Размер разъема "мама" rj-45 минимум 2х2х2 сантиметра - что не подходит для носимых устройств.

Кабель же толстый и гнется ограниченное количество раз.

Comment: не очень убедительно. Может дело в питании?

Comment: в чем проблема с питанием по витой паре? 50 Ватт без проблем